# Text align justify on li moves bullets on text in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-lists

Text align justify moves bullet points on the text contents on certain line in Firefox. Is there a way to avoid this behavior.
Below snippet will show the anomaly if you open it in Firefox. It works fine in Chrome & IE (I checked in IE10/IE11).

As showing on Firefox:
[image: Firefox]

As showing in Chrome
[image: Chrome]

```css
ul li{text-align:justify;}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Property was occupied by Doe Family for past 17  years where in seller Mr. John Doe owner of collateral through CD  claims execution of sale deed with mutual consent. On joint visit by credit and sales team it  was found that there are two parallel title chain of the collateral:</li>
  <li>Way back in 2000-01 John Doe and  his brother entered into collaboration with some Creater Jane Doe and  it was decided that G+2 structure will be built. GF &amp; 1st will go to both  the brothers and 2nd to builder.  But no  collaboration agreement was entered on paper. Further builder  breaching the mutually agreed terms constructed 3rd floor as well  -&gt; Accordingly builder  claimed occupancy n rights on both 2nd and 3rd floor &ndash; property went into  dispute</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce on FF ... can you show a screen of what you see

Comment: @Temani same for me.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Firefox quantum

Comment: Hi, Added the same, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the below property:

- list-style-position: outside;

Please check the following [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_list-style-position)

Comment: Thanks peteb for your answer, tried that already. Didn't worked. And as I know, outside is the default attribute of list-style-position, if you haven't changed it explicitly. The only thing which is solving the problem is putting a block level element (I tried div, p) inside li for the text content.

Comment: You can also try to hide the list style and use the :before with content:"●";